# In Mono, how do I get the path to the Documents folder on a Mac (Snow Leopard)?

Tags: macos, mono, osx-snow-leopard, special-folders

I'm writing a Mono application and would like to find the full path of the Documents folder - e.g. `/Users/johnsmith/Documents/`. What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: You do know that you can access at ~/Documents, right?

Comment: Yes, but I need it expanded (to display).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this:

```
string doc_path = Path.Combine (Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "Documents");
```

(Btw, for MonoTouch, It's just `Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal)`).