# F# Directory and paths in MacOS X 10.11.3

Tags: macos, file, path, f#

Hi i'm a newbie in MacOS X (10.11.3) and have used so far F# in VS2015 on Win8.1

I have some questions:

1- in F# Interactive,
if i wanna say, have the list of files of the directory ~/Documents

`Directory.GetFiles(@"~/Documents")` doesn't work. What is the right syntax ?

if i want to do a `#r xxx.dll`, how do i specify rightly the path

2- same question in a source file (.fs or .fsx)

thanks

EDIT for example I get the following in F# interactive

> let CD = "/Documents";;

val CD : string = "/Documents"

> Directory.GetFiles(CD);;

System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Directory '/Documents' not found.

> at System.IO.Directory.ValidateDirectoryListing (System.String path, System.String searchPattern, System.Boolean& stop) <0x1a22580 + 0x001f8> in 0 
>     at System.IO.Directory.GetFileSystemEntries (System.String path, System.String searchPattern, FileAttributes mask, FileAttributes attrs) <0x1a22800 + 0x00061> in 0 
>     at System.IO.Directory.GetFiles (System.String path, System.String searchPattern) <0x1a21bf0 + 0x00034> in 0 
>     at System.IO.Directory.GetFiles (System.String path) <0x1a21bb0 + 0x00027> in 0 
>     at FSI_0031.main@ () <0x73a07f0 + 0x00013> in 0 
>     at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
>     at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) <0x1a7c850 + 0x000a1> in 0 
>   Stopped due to error

Comment: When you say doesn't work - what happens? 2 - you need the directory name in quotes

Comment: Sorry - for 2 it should be the dll name in quotes - like `#r "file.dll"`

Comment: Thx! Well, does that /Documents folder exist? Or is it some sort of special folder? Can you try `Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal),"Documents")`    from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933975/in-mono-how-do-i-get-the-path-to-the-documents-folder-on-a-mac-snow-leopard

Comment: also since you will be accessing paths with \ or / in them I would use `let mydir = @"/Documents"`

Comment: I'm a noob in MacOS X but if i open the Terminal, i type 'ls' and i can definitely see a directory called "Documents"

Comment: Path.Combine (...) works. The typical path is /Users/User_name/Documents etc... thanks vm !!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume maybe you're using Mono/Xamarin? I don't have experience with MacOS but .NET should be available. You can access your home directory with:     `System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERPROFILE")`                   There are also other variables accessing special folders but I'm not sure how windows specific is that.      For your second question you can use `#I @"path/to/dll"` to specify the folder where the dll is and then add the dll name with `#r @"file.dll"`. This works in both fs and fsx files. You might want put this in between `#if INTERACTIVE #endif` block. And for compiled stuff you can add the reference to the DLL in your IDE directly.